# NHibernate and WinForms

Tags: c#

I' ve mapped tables from the database to NHIbernate object. But I don't know how can I display
these objects in DataGridView? To bind list of objects with datagridview I can use bindingsource and than I can use Filter for exapmle. But I don't know if it is good solution from NHiberante ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a bindingsource to bind the data. Just assign a collection of objects to the Grid's data source property.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = session.Query<EntityType>();
```

Comment: Sorry, but ISession doesn't have function Query

Comment: I want to use Filter and collection must implement Ibinding interface

Comment: It has, just add `using NHibernate.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: Yes, it has, but IBinding is still not impelment in IQueryable interface and Filter in BindingSource doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to wrap nHibernate's output in a `BindingList`?

Comment: Not yet, but this is probably the only solution